# git lfs 404 error: decipher error message to deduce file name

Tags: git-lfs

I am moving several Git repositories that use LFS. I'm able to clone the repo into new system, then manually retrieve LFS files and upload. Command sequence is:

1. Create the new repo.  We used Azure ADO import, which worked OK, but it does not bring in the LFS files.
2. Clone that new repo. Call that `origin`
3. Manually get LFS files

   A. `git remote add source URL_FOR_ORIGINAL_REPO`

   B. `git lfs fetch source --all`

   C. `git lfs push origin --all`

All good, except

In one case, a few files are missing from the source server, most likely because of a user error in the past.  Since users have come and gone, there's no guarantee we can find that user or their computer.

But I need to know what is missing.  Here's how the problem looks.  When we try to fetch, error is like this

```
$ git lfs fetch source --all
fetch: 490 object(s) found, done.
fetch: Fetching all references...
[24d6ffa33aa5a786b0f0d0f542c2660bc886b14ce15203ea78cf971e5447e8ca] LFS object not found: [404] LFS object not found
[4ffaa18643534971c53b3bf3e419d51ebb6735449ef745626e17f8521cf92fe6] LFS object not found: [404] LFS object not found
[575b9fb4521dc75e39ec2741b75486f2069cf6baf0d00338129bb2a6f6dfcbad] LFS object not found: [404] LFS object not found
```

How can I trace from this

```
[24d6ffa33aa5a786b0f0d0f542c2660bc886b14ce15203ea78cf971e5447e8ca]
```

to the name of the branch and file that are missing from the repo?

It seems like there should have a simple answer, but I'm not finding any.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35266717/1086346 : from 2016, suggests we run `git lfs push --object-id origin 24d6ffa33aa5a786b0f0d0f542c2660bc886b14ce15203ea78cf971e5447e8ca` but if I don't have the source file, how will this help?

https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/4099 : same problem, infeasible suggestions

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68591097/1086346 : doesn't explain how to get file path

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got the file name in the same situation:

`git lfs ls-files -a -l | grep 24d6ffa33aa5a786b0f0d0f542c2660bc886b14ce15203ea78cf971e5447e8ca`

-a option lists all LFS files, not just those currently checked out. -l lists the full hash, not just the first 10 digits.